# session problem in using WebRequest and WebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

i have created an application with the help of webrequest and webresponse . when i try to log in to yahoo i succeed. after that i open the next page and i get the login page again by the response. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you add the code that you have to your question?

Answer (score 3):

If I'd have to guess (which I do, given the current state of the question), I'd say you have neglected to support cookies in your request.

Answer (score 2):

I think you already answered your own question, almost anyway (you guessed this was session-related).  You need to keep track of the cookies that the initial login request sets, and send those cookies back on subsequent requests.